# Books on line codes?

Tags: communication, books

Would you recommend any good book dealing with line codes (i.e. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_code).

I mean a book that goes a little bit deeper into properties of each encoding (e.g. spectrum). I believe this topic is discussed in many digital communications text books, but there are too many of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my shelf I have
B. P. Lathi. "Modern Digital and Analog Communication Systems". 1983. (Should I upgrade to a later edition?)

In section "3.2: Line Coding", it has a description and frequency spectrum for a few line codes: on-off, polar, bipolar (pseudoternary), duobinary, split-phase (Manchester), high-density bipolar (HDB3). It mentions "A list of codes ... can be found in Bylanski and Ingram.".

P. Bylanski and D. G. W. Ingram, "Digital Transmission Systems", Peter Peregrinus Ltd., Herts., England, 1976

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question - after reviewing all the books I could find around, it seems that the classic "Digital Communications" by Glover & Grant was enough for what I was looking for (Chapter 6: Baseband transmission and line codes, 6.4. Line coding).

I've also found this great PDF:
http://gemini.udistrital.edu.co/comunidad/profesores/hjeslavab/Downloads/Codigos%20de%20linea.pdf

Comment: I glanced at the document you're referring to and I noticed an error in the top line of figure 6.1. It says "bipolar RZ", but should read "bipolar NRZ". Didn't read it completely, so I don't know if there are other errors.

Comment: Yeah, you're perfectly right - the first figure is NRZ. I need to read it carefully :)